# Why this reduce function call does not work in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, reduce

Using Common Lisp (SBCL), I can successfully evaluate in REPL:

```lisp
CL-USER> (reduce #'+ '(1 2 3 4))
10
```

However, this fails:

```lisp
> (reduce #'(lambda (e) (+ e 100))  '(1 2 3 4))
```

The debugger throws an error:

> invalid number of arguments: 2

I was expecting an accumulating effect, so the sum would be `110`.

How can I achieve the expected result? Do I need to use something else than `reduce`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reducing function must accept two arguments. Your lambda function accepts only one. Even if it worked it would add `100` to your result on each step of the additions along the list.

What you mean is specifying the initial value. The simplest hacky way is just to cons it onto your list, like

```
> (reduce #'+ (cons 100 '(1 2 3 4)))
110
```

The proper way, going by [the specs](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm), is to explicitly specify it with the `:initial-value` [keyword parameter](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_k.htm#keyword_parameter):

```
> (reduce #'+ '(1 2 3 4) :initial-value 100)
110
```

And if you do want to add the `100` on each reduction step,

```
> (reduce #'(lambda (a x) (+ 100 a x)) '(1 2 3 4))
310
```

You might want to add one more `100` by specifying is as the `:initial-value` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `(reduce #'f '(1 2 3 4))` will compute

```
(f (f (f 1 2) 3) 4)
```

So for example

```
>>> (reduce #'(lambda (a b) (cons a b)) '(1 2 3 4))
(((1 . 2) . 3) . 4)
```

Thus, the function you pass to `reduce` needs to accept two arguments. This function is first called with the first two elements of the sequence. Then the function is called with result of the previous call and the next element in the sequence and so on (see [[CLHS reduce](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm)]). To obtain the sum of all elements you need to call the following:

```
>>> (reduce #'(lambda (a b) (+ a b)) '(1 2 3 4))
10
```

The behavior of `reduce` can be altered by providing an initial value. Calling

```
(reduce #'f '(1 2 3 4) :initial-value 100)
```

will compute the following:

```
(f (f (f (f 100 1) 2) 3) 4)
```

Thus, if you want to get the desired result you can use:

```
>>> (reduce #'+ '(1 2 3 4) :initial-value 100)
110
```

To add 100 to each of the numbers and then compute the sum, you can use a combination of `reduce` and `mapcar`, which is a common pattern in functional programming:

```
>>> (reduce #'+ (mapcar #'(lambda (a) (+ a 100)) '(1 2 3 4)))
410
```

Comment: Thanks. What about how to get  100 added on each "iteration" of reduce? The final result would be 410

Comment: @PedroDelfino if you wanted to add 100 on each iteration, e.g., something like `(reduce '+ (mapcar (lambda (x) (+ x 100)) '(1 2 3 4))`, you could use the `:key` argument to reduce: `(reduce '+ '(1 2 3 4) :key (lambda (x) (+ x 100)))`.